# A generic list of generics

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

I'm trying to store a list of generic objects in a generic list, but I'm having difficulty declaring it. My object looks like:

```
public class Field<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

I'd like to create a list of these. My problem is that each object in the list can have a separate type, so that the populated list could contain something like this:

```
{ Field<DateTime>, Field<int>, Field<double>, Field<DateTime> }
```

So how do I declare that?

```
List<Field<?>>
```

(I'd like to stay as typesafe as possible, so I don't want to use an ArrayList).

Comment: It's an interesting idea to "stay as typesafe as possible", however, aren't you violating the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI concept? Think about how are you going to access that list, do you really need it that specific?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is situation where it *may* benefit you to have an abstract base class (or interface) containing the non-generic bits:

```
public abstract class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Field<T> : Field
{    
    public T Value { get; set; }

    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Then you can have a `List<Field>`. That expresses all the information you actually know about the list. You don't know the types of the fields' values, as they can vary from one field to another.

Comment: @Jon - Should the first class be a generic or just a simple class?

Comment: @Giorgi, `abstract class Field<T>` looks like a typo. I've taken the liberty of correcting it.

Comment: He still has to cast to get the actual value type... but this is about the only solution that I can think of too, without an actual "tuple" type.

Comment: @tames, he's in a better position because the elements of his list must inherit from Field (or implement IField, in my example). The list is still more strongly typed than a list of objects

Comment: @anthony... I agree, and I have used both interface and base class solutions.

Answer (score 6):

You can't declare a list of generic types without knowing the generic type at compile time.

You can declare a `List<Field<int>>` or a `List<Field<double>>`, but there is no other common base type for `Field<int>` and `Field<double>` than `object`. So the only `List<T>` that could hold different kinds of fields would be `List<object>`.

If you want a more specific type for the list, you would have to make the `Field<T>` class inherit a class or implement an interface. Then you can use that for the generic type in the list.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps implement an interface.

```
interface IField
{
}

class Field<T> : IField
{
}
```

...

```
List<IField> fields = new List<IField>() { new Field<int>(), new Field<double>() };
```

Comment: This leaves him in the same position because IField won't contain the type (T).  Not a whole lot different from just using `object` because he'll still have to cast to get the value.

Comment: @tames, he's in a better position because the elements of his list must implement IField (or inherit from Field, in Jon's example). The list is still more strongly typed than a list of objects.

Comment: @anthony... I agree, and I have used both interface and base class solutions.